# How to Speed up RetrievalQA Chain?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I have created a RetrievalQA chain and now want to speed up the process. At the moment, the generation of the text takes too long (1-2minutes) with the qunatized Mixtral 8x7B-Instruct model from "TheBloke".

I am running the chain locally on a Macbook Pro (Apple M2 Max) with 64GB RAM, and 12 cores.

Here is my code:

```
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
import box
import yaml
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# Import config vars
with open('config/config.yml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as ymlfile:
    cfg = box.Box(yaml.safe_load(ymlfile))


def build_llm(model_path):
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

        n_gpu_layers = 1 # Metal set to 1 is enough. # ausprobiert mit mehreren
        n_batch = 1024 # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of RAM of your Apple Silicon Chip.

        llm = LlamaCpp(
                max_tokens =cfg.MAX_TOKENS,
                #model_path="/Documents/rag_example/Modelle/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q5_K_M.gguf",
                model_path=model_path,
                temperature=0.1,
                f16_kv=True,
                n_ctx=28000, # 28k because Mixtral can take up to 32k  
                n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
                n_batch=n_batch,
                callback_manager=callback_manager, 
                verbose=True, # Verbose is required to pass to the callback manager
                top_p=0.75,
                top_k=40,
                model_kwargs={
                        'repetition_penalty': 1.1,
                        'mirostat': 2,
                },
        )
        
        return llm

mistral_prompt = """
<s> [INST] Du bist ein hilfreicher Chat-Assistent names Mixtral, der nur auf Deutsch antworten kann.
Deine Aufgabe ist es, die Fragen des Nutzers ausschließlich auf Deutsch zu beantworten.
Nutze den gefundenen Kontext, um die Fragen zu beantworten. 
Falls du die Antwort nicht weißt, sag einfach, dass du die Antwort nicht kennst.
Falls sich die Antwort nicht im Kontext befindet, antworte: "Es gibt nicht genug Informationen im Kontext, um die Frage zu beantworten.".
Halte deine Antworten präzise und vermeide spekulative oder erfundene Informationen.
Erfinde nichts, falls du die Antwort nicht kennst oder du dir nicht sicher bist!
Ein Konversationsverlauf steht dir nach "Chat History" zur Verfügung.
Wenn du merkst, dass der Nutzer Smalltalk betreibt, führe Smalltalk mit ihm.

Chat History: {chat_history}

Context: {context} 

Question: {question} 
Answer: [/INST]
"""

def set_mistral_prompt():
    """
    Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vectorstore
    """
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=mistral_prompt,
                            input_variables=['chat_history', 'context', 'question'])
    return prompt

def build_retrieval_qa(llm, prompt, vectordb, chain_type="RetrievalQA"):
    chain_type_kwargs={
        #"verbose": True,
        "prompt": prompt,
        "memory": ConversationBufferMemory(
            memory_key="chat_history",
            input_key="question",
            #output_key="answer",
            return_messages=True),
        "verbose": False
        }
    
    if chain_type == "RetrievalQA":
        dbqa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                        chain_type='stuff',
                                        retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': cfg.VECTOR_COUNT, 'score_treshold': cfg.SCORE_TRESHOLD}, search_type="similarity"), # search_type="mmr" for Similarity AND diversity
                                        return_source_documents=cfg.RETURN_SOURCE_DOCUMENTS,
                                        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
                                        verbose=False
                                        )
    return dbqa




from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings, HuggingFaceEmbeddings, SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
import pickle
from src.utils import setup_dbqa, build_retrieval_qa, set_mistral_prompt
from src.utils import setup_dbqa
from src.text_preprocess import clean_document, clean_document_confluence
from src.llm import build_llm

# Load documents
with open(f'confluence_docs.pkl', 'rb') as documents:
    documents = pickle.load(documents)
    
# Preprocess the text before chunking
documents = clean_document_confluence(documents)
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="intfloat/multilingual-e5-large",
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'mps'})

vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)

chat_history = []    
qa_prompt = set_mistral_prompt()
llm = build_llm(model_path="/Users/mweissenba001/Documents/rag_example/Modelle/mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q5_K_M.gguf")
mixtral_qa = build_retrieval_qa(llm=llm,prompt=qa_prompt,vectordb=vectorstore)

mixtral_qa({'query': "Wer ist Dr. Nicolai Bieber?", "chat_history": []}) # takes longer than 1min
```

So which steps may I have to adapt to get faster responses? The Mixtral-Model without the RetrievalQA chain only takes a couple of seconds.

Increasing "n_gpu_layers" and "n_batch" didn't really help. I also added "n_threads = 8" to llm = LlamaCpp(...)

Comment: How much latency is added in RetriveQA pipeline?

Comment: How can I check this?